# Another Form For A Sum Of Geometric progression

Tags: calculus, summation

I have the following summation: $$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+...+\frac{1}{2^{22}}$$

Which is the sum of the $23$ elements of a $32$ bit mantissa.

Now the sum is:

$$\frac{\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{2^{23}}-1)}{\frac{1}{2}-1}=-(2^{-23}-1)=1-2^{-23}$$

In the note it was calculate by $$(2^{23}-1)2^{-23}$$ which is the same, but how did we get to this formula this from the first place?

Comment: what 32 bit mantissa is about? just use $\frac{1}{2}=2^{-1}$ and all will be simple and clear.

Comment: Which formula? $1-2^{-23}=2^{-23}(2^{23}-1)$, or $\sum_{k=1}^{22} 2^{-k}=\frac{\frac12(2^{-23}-1)}{\frac12-1}$?

Comment: There are $22$ terms in your series, not $23$.

Comment: @Gae.S. $2^{-23}(2^23-1)$

Comment: Just collect the $2^{-23}$ by distributivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the expression $1-2^{-23}$, multiply and divide by $2^{-23}$. So, you obtain:
$$\frac{1-2^{-23}}{2^{-23}}\cdot2^{-23}=(\frac{1}{2^{-23}}-1)\cdot2^{-23}=(2^{23}-1)\cdot2^{-23}$$

Answer (score 1):

The sum is $1-\frac{1}{2^{22}}$
$$$$
Denote that $$T=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+...+\frac{1}{2^{22}}$$
Then we have 
$$2T=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+...+\frac{1}{2^{21}}$$
Hence,$$T=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+...+\frac{1}{2^{21}}-(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+...+\frac{1}{2^{22}})=1-\frac{1}{2^{22}}$$

Answer (score 0):

let $s=1+\frac1r+\frac1{r^2}...eq-1$ multiply with r on both sides we get $r*s=r+1+\frac1r+\frac1{r^2}...eq-2$ substituting eq-1 in eq-2 we get $r*s=r+s==>s=\frac{r}{r-1}$ 
which can be written as $\frac1{1-{\frac1r}}$ where s:-is sum & r:-is common ratio.from above basic derivation you can get your formula.